# How to change the position of fab with onTouchListener?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using Floating Action Button. I want to change the position of fab when the user touch the fab and drag it. I am using onTouchListener but it does not move the fab well.
Here is my code:

```
final FloatingActionButton fabButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
    .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fab))
    .withButtonColor(Color.WHITE)
    .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT)
    .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
    .create();
    fabButton.setAlpha(0.6f);
    fabButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fabButton.setX(event.getX());
            fabButton.setY(event.getY());

            return false;
        }
    });
```

thanks from any suggestions in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `return false`; If listener returns false on finger down event, then move event is ignored, in simple words. Try this code:

```
fabButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        float x, y;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    fabButton.setX(fabButton.getX() + (event.getX() - x));
                    fabButton.setY(fabButton.getY() + (event.getY() - y));
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Also, as `x` and `y` are coordinates of left top corner of view, you probably don't want to set `x` and `y` of touch as these coordinates. Instead, you should calculate delta of movement and increase initial coordinates of fab, as I specified in the snippet above

Comment: this does not work for me. I'm on android studio 4.2 C15 using SDK 30

Comment: @MiguelSilva could you share your code via i.e. pastebin?

Comment: in the meantime found why I'm using a custom-made floating action button. and that code snippet needed some tweaks.

Comment: I am also in the process of making it an open-source library. You can find it here:  https://github.com/aeonSolutions/FloatingActionButtonMenuDrag

Comment: Did you try returning `true` in the handled cases of switch in [this function](https://github.com/aeonSolutions/FloatingActionButtonMenuDrag/blob/c8fb3bb4c6c2d0409b17b13882aeca4e0e9a9617/FloatingActionButtonMenuDrag/src/main/java/aeonlabs/solutions/common/layout/fab/FloatingActionButton.java#L547)? The problem might be that no matter what you do in this function, it will always return `super.onTouchEvent()`